# Trying Upload same file in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I am working to develop a Windows form Project, we should use a Product picture.
Every this working well, we use File.Exists() to check if the file already exists then copy the image to the product Image folder.

```
if (image.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(image.FileName))
{
    _view.FirmLogo.Image = new Bitmap(image.FileName);
    _view.LogoURL = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\"), @"Resources\ProductImage\", Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                
    //
    if (File.Exists(_view.LogoURL))
    {
        File.Delete(_view.LogoURL);
    }
    //File.Move(@"c:\test\SomeFile.txt", @"c:\test\Test\SomeFile.txt");
    File.Copy(image.FileName, _view.LogoURL);
}
```

**The Bug**
when we try to update the same file it fired an error:
"because it is being used by another process.
Ex. if we upload pic1, everything is well, we try to change to pic2 great job.
but if we try to back the pic1 fired the error especially if it happens in the same seesion.

Comment: Determine which process is using the file. Use sysinternals tools.

Comment: did you set permission for delete file in your host?